# How to hide div with jquery within the UpdatePanel onClick event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ButtonId").click(function () {

        $('#DivID').hide();

    });

});
```

This is not working for me. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Most probable causes :

- not unique ID (only one element can have a given ID in a document, use a class if you can't make it unique)
- dynamically created button (use `$(document.body).on('click', "#ButtonId", function () {`)

Answer (score 0):

Controls with runat="server" have their IDs changed when the page is rendered (there are ways around this, but its not the default functionality). If the initial answer of ensuring the ID is unique didn't work for you, ensure you are referencing the correct ID. You can get the rendered ID by doing YourElementID.ClientID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#<%= ButtonId.ClientID %>').click(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys.

I want to share with you how I managed to manipulate the div inside the UpdatePanel. Here is what I did to resolve my issue:

```
  function pageLoad() {
     $(function () {

            if(Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {

                  $('.DivClass').hide();
            }  
     });
 }
```

With the function pageLoad() and get_isInAsyncPostBack() I could track partial update of UpdatePanel and in this way I could hide my div when it occurred.